# WP Woocommerce filter product category list widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce on which I have to display a sidebar widget on the Product Categories archive pages.

That's an easy one with the WC_Widget_Product_Categories, but I have to hook onto that widget in order for me to output only the first level siblings of the current parent (if no siblings, then show the current level).

This was once a behavior on the older WC versions, but hasn't been ported. [A comment here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/only-show-children-of-current-category-no-longer-showing/#post-16220714) stated that I could use the Classic Widget for legacy, but that's not the way I want to go.

What is the correct way of hooking into the widget in order to filter the output the way I want it ?

Comment: Which WC version are you currently using?

Comment: I'm currently running on v7.7.0

Comment: So go check the source code, to see which filters it applies: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-product-categories.php There's four `apply_filters` calls in there, so your options are limited to using those.

Comment: That I've done, tried each of the four filters but it never seemed to enter the filter function i defined ...

Comment: Based on this comment, the filters will only work with the lecacy widget, not the block eitor! https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-categories-widget-3/#post-15734537

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to mean. You said you were using WC_Widget_Product_Categories, and that clearly still applies those filters?

Comment: I'm adding the widget via the Widget admin section, called "Product Categories List". Not sure what portion of code that refers to.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I actually worked around with the creation of my own custom widget, way easier than trying to fix the WC way.

I followed the code given here : https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-widget-in-wordpress#Where_to_Begin_When_Creating_a_Custom_Widget

Works like a charm, using [get_ancestors()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)